# We were thinking of porting our site into wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We have a lot of media posts by users in the site.  I just don't know where to begin.  Is there any book or site you would recommend that provides the Wordpress schema and elaborates on a "porting process?"

Tx

Comment: Port from where? This needs *way* more detail to make sense.

Comment: Do you want to export from Wordpress to another site? Is the target site also Wordpress? As mentioned, more details are required before you can get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does include plenty of import tools for the content that you might be hosting elsewhere.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Import_Screen

http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content

I am currently migrating a site myself that was in plain-old static html to WordPress. 
And my nifty little plugin has been extremely helpful. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/